# Does using both tmpfs and zram make any sense?

Tags: performance, tmpfs, optimization, zram

I wondered if [tmpfs](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/16244/) and [zram](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html) do negatively interfere with each other in any way?
After what I've read about it I'm unsure whether there is a positive cumulative effect accomplishable with that combination.

Has someone made experiences with that combination?

Thank you in advance for useful answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer the question I think you're asking, it is possible to use these two together, and doing so won't cause any ill effects on the other.

I don't know if you are familiar with `/dev/shm`, but it's a filesystem mounted in RAM which appears to be a folder. **SHM, tmpfs and zram are all slightly different implementations which lead to the same output** - storage of data in RAM instead of a secondary storage device. As far as I know, the differences lie in how they react when RAM starts filling up.

Since you're asking this question you've probably heard of swap - when memory reaches near-full capacity, the OS starts moving data between RAM and a dedicated partition. From what I remember, and this might be wrong, but tmpfs will only be swapped *when absolutely necessary*, and will always try to remain in RAM. `/dev/shm` can be swapped as readily as any other data in RAM, and I don't know about zram but I suspect it's the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question!